# How do I insert into a table with a select statement?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with a join table.  Here is my schema.

```
SOLDIERS
  SOLDIER_ID     integer
  FIRST_NAME  varchar(50)
  LAST_NAME   varchar(50)

RANKS
  RANK_ID        integer
  NAME        varchar(50)

SOLDIER_RANKS
  SOLDIER_ID     integer
  RANK_ID        integer
```

I am trying to insert a row into the `SOLDIER_RANKS` table.  I know the `id` of the `SOLDIER` and I know the `name` of the `RANK`.  Here is what I have tried, but I can't figure out how to hard code the `SOLDIER_ID`.

```
 INSERT INTO SOLDIER RANKS(SOLDIER_ID, RANK_ID)
  // Here I need to specify that SOLDIER_ID = 1
  SELECT RANK.RANK_ID WHERE RANK.NAME = 'COLONEL';
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 4):

No need to use a values clause:

```
INSERT INTO SOLDIER_RANKS(SOLDIER_ID, RANK_ID)
SELECT 1,
       RANK.RANK_ID
WHERE  RANK.NAME = 'COLONEL';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO SOLDIER_RANKS(SOLDIER_ID, RANK_ID)
values (
  -- Here I need to specify that SOLDIER_ID = 1
  1,  
  (SELECT RANK.RANK_ID from <rank-table-name> RANK WHERE RANK.NAME = 'COLONEL')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these any of one method

```
INSERT INTO SOLDIER RANKS(SOLDIER_ID, RANK_ID)
values 
(
  1,  
  (SELECT RANK.RANK_ID FROM RANKS WHERE RANK.NAME = 'COLONEL')
);
```

OR

```
  INSERT INTO SOLDIER RANKS(SOLDIER_ID, RANK_ID)
  SELECT
  1,  
  RANK.RANK_ID 
  FROM RANKS WHERE RANK.NAME = 'COLONEL'
```